# Как передать ссылку в виде регулярного выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения, ruby

Есть `answers_controller_spec.rb`:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe AnswersController do
  let(:question) { create(:question) }
  let(:answer) { create(:answer, question: question, user: @user) }
  let(:anothers_answer) { create(:answer, question: question) }

  describe 'POST #create' do
    context 'with valid attributes' do
      let(:subject) { post :create, question_id: question, answer: attributes_for(:answer), format: :json }

      sign_in_user

      it_behaves_like 'publishable'
    end
  end
end
```

и private_pub.rb

```
shared_examples_for 'publishable' do |channel|
  it 'publishes object' do
    expect(PrivatePub).to receive(:publish_to).with(channel, anything)
    subject
  end
end
```

Как мне в `answers_controller_spec.rb` ссылку на канал `/questions/#{question.id}/answers` написать в виде регулярного выражения, что бы передать ее как параметр через `it_behaves_like 'publishable', ......` в `shared_examples`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
it_behaves_like "publishable", %r{^\/questions\/\d+\/answers$}
```